# How to check if Apache is stopped or crashed with Ossec?

Tags: monitoring

How can I check if Apache is running or has crashed with Ossec?

I'm adding the following in the ossec.conf on one of the agents:

```
<localfile>
   <log_format>full_command</log_format>
   <command>service httpd status</command>
</localfile>
```

But nothing is showing up, even when I stop apache.

What could the reason be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should write your rules (if it does not exist in /var/ossec/rules/).
my setup for rsyslog service is:

in /var/ossec/etc/ossec.conf at agent, I added

```
   <localfile>
      <log_format>command</log_format>
      <command>service rsyslog status</command>
      <frequency>45</frequency>
      <alias>Rsyslog Service Status</alias>
   </localfile>
```

in /var/ossec/rules/local_rules.xml at ossec-server,

```
   <rule id="110102" level="1">
      <if_sid>530</if_sid>
      <match>ossec: output: 'Rsyslog Service Status':</match>
      <options>no_log</options>
      <group>rsyslog</group>
   </rule>

   <rule id="110103" level="10">
      <if_sid>110102</if_sid>
      <match>Active: inactive</match>
      <description>Rsyslog service is inactive (STOP).</description>
      <group>rsyslog</group>
   </rule>

   <rule id="110104" level="10">
      <if_sid>110102</if_sid>
      <match>Active: failed</match>
      <description>Rsyslog service is inactive (FAILED).</description>
      <group>rsyslog</group>
   </rule>
```

**NOT** Also you can deploy the first part in /var/ossec/etc/ossec.conf at the ossec-server instead of agent. If you do that, you should set **logcollector.remote_commands=1**

**NOT** Do not forget to *./ossec-control restart*